# iPhone retina simulator window not able to move above screen

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I run the iPhone retina simulator in Xcode it stops if from moving above the top of the screen, but the simulator window is bigger than my monitor, so I can't see what's at the bottom of the simulator window, how can I change things so I can move it upwards off the top of the monitor screen?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use cmd+2 or cmd+3 to fit simulator to your screen.

Comment: Or cmd+1. Smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll the *Display* of the Simulator with the two-finger scroll.

Can look like this on a 15" retina

[image]

Comment: My game fits perfectly within the simulator screen, so there's no need for me to scroll it(no scroll bars anyway), I just want to be able to move the sim window up so the top goes off the top and I can see the bottom.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. When the simulator can't be fully displayed the "content" in the window is scrollable (the simulators display). Will add an screenshot

Comment: I'm not getting any scroll indicators, and anyway I still don't want to scroll it, I just want to move it above the menu bar.

Comment: It is basically the same as moving the "window" as the window is shorter than the laptop screen (you see it ends just above the dock in the screenshot)

Comment: My window goes below the dock, but that's what I'm saying it won't allow me to move the window any higher than the menu bar.

Comment: weird!? what happens if you change "hardware" between non-retina iPhone and retina iPad?

Comment: If I do that I get scroll bars, just not for retina iPhone.